# Getting 0 count in message object using pop3 protocol when try to read the messages from Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: java, pop3

Trying to read email from java code by using POP3 protocol.
I am using client email server microsoft outlook 2016(POP3 protocol) .But not able get the messages and messages count . Luckily ,i am able to send messages from my java code .
Can anyone Help me out what went wrong ?Thanks in advance.

public String ReadMail() throws MessagingException, IOException {

```
    // Get system properties
    int count = 5;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        try
        {

 Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "110");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", "example.outlook.com");


            // properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.port", "pop3"), port);


        properties.setProperty(
                String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.fallback", "pop3"),
                "false");



        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,null);
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("example.outlook.com, username, password);
        System.out.println(store);


            if (getInboxFolder() != null)
            {
                Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
                for (Message msg : msgs)
                {
                    if (msg.getSubject().contains("Test"))
                    {
                        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                        BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
                        bp.getContent();
                        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) msg.getContent();
                        String bodyContent = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
                        return bodyContent;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            count--;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            count--;
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

I would like to read messages from my java code . What is the problem? Why it doesn't work in this case?